# How can I make the map of Russia in R without splitting it? The split is happening because of the prime meridian

Tags: r, plot, maps, r-sp, rgdal

I am trying to make a Russian map. I have already tried several tips, but nothing is working for me.

Initially, I was trying just to use spplot:

```
library(rgdal)
gadm= getData('GADM', country = 'RUS', level = 1)
gadm$regions = as.factor(1:83)
spplot(gadm, "regions")
```

Then I have realised that there is a problem beacause of the prime meridian, so i've tried this:

```
gadm_new <- spTransform(gadm, CRS("+proj=longlat +lon_wrap=105"))
spplot(gadm_new, "regions")
```

[Result was the same](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Xedl.png)

My last attempt failed as well

```
proj4.str <- CRS("+init=epsg:3413 +lon_0=105")
gadm.prj <- spTransform(gadm, proj4.str)
spplot(gadm.prj, "regions")
```

[I've turned it upside down somehow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tGLTA.png)

I am desperate for help!

Answer (score 0):

I have figured that out:

```
library(rgdal)
library(RColorBrewer)
library(raster)

gadm=getData('GADM', country = 'RUS', level = 1)
chukotka=gadm@polygons[[12]]
for (i in 1:length(chukotka@Polygons)) {
  polygon_long <- chukotka@Polygons[[i]]@coords[, 1]
  if (mean(polygon_long) < 0) {
    polygon_long <- 360 + polygon_long
  }
  chukotka@Polygons[[i]]@coords[, 1] <- polygon_long
}

gadm@polygons[[12]]=chukotka
gadm$regions = as.factor(1:83)
my.palette=brewer.pal(n = 9, name = "OrRd")
spplot(gadm, "regions", xlim=c(15,190), ylim=c(40,83), col.regions = my.palette, cuts = 4, col = "transparent")
```